# Integer.parseInt(string, radix) in Java returns (mostly) negative decimal values

Tags: java, hex, mac-address, negative-number

As I said above I am using Integer.parseInt to convert hex values into decimal but I keep getting returned negative integers when I put in positive hex values:

```
byte[] bytes2 = getMacBytes("90:e6:ba:97:4a:bb");

private static byte[] getMacBytes(String macStr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[6];
    String[] hex = macStr.split("(\\:|\\-)");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        System.out.println(hex[i]);
    }
    if (hex.length != 6) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid MAC address.");
    }
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
            System.out.println(bytes[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex digit in MAC address.");
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

when I run this code it returns this:

90
e6
ba
97
4a
bb
-112
-26
-70
-105
74
-69

So I can see the MAC address is being split properly, but 5 of the 6 hex values are being returned from Integer.parseInt(string, radix) as negative. I can see that the negative values are x + 256 of their actual decimal value but the second last is the correct decimal value...
Any ideas why it is turning 5 of the 6 values into negatives?

Comment: Did you try to add `0x` in front of your `hex[i]` `String`s to have Java interpret it as hexadecimal ?

Comment: @Y__: That's what the radix is for.

Comment: Ho sorry didn't saw it :(

Answer (score 10):

I think parseInt is behaving correctly, but your cast to byte converts the numbers to the range [-128; 127]. Try storing the results in a short or int array, or keep them in a byte array, but remember to print them with `System.out.println(bytes[i] & 0xff)`.

Comment: @ lachs: Remember that `byte` in Java is a **signed** number in the range -128 to 127. So `(byte)200` is `-56`.

Comment: Thankyou so much marcus & everyone else! I knew it must be something simple but not this simple. I feel like a major n00b. Have an awesome night/day whatever it is where you are and thanks again!